# Count number of spaces before index in java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am dealing with long strings, and they will have a certain number of spaces in places in the middle. I know what the index of the beginning letter of the word after the space, how can i count the number of spaces that come before that index in java? Thank you for your time.

This is what I tried to do:

```
int num = s.indexOf("name");
char t = ' ';
int j = 0;
while(t == ' ') {
t = s.charAt((num - j));
    j++;
}
int spaceCount = num - ((num - j) + 1);
String space = "";
for(int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++) {
    space += " ";
}
```

Then I would add the space variable to the index "num". It doesn't seem to be working, though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of spaces before given position/string:

```
int pos = s.indexOf("name");
int spaceCount = 0;
for (int i = pos -1; i >= 0 && s.charAt(i) == ' '; i--) {  
    spaceCount ++;
}
// number of spaces: spaceCount
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two words with undefined number of spaces in between, what about finding the end index of the first and the start index of the second word and calculate the difference of these two numbers?

Comment: This is what I was attempting to do, but I think where I went wrong was finding the ending index of the first word. I tried to do that using a for loop, but I think that's where I had trouble. The problem is I don't know what the first word is, however I do know the second.

Comment: Your code seems way to complicated for this task, I have thought of something like for (int i = startIndex; i > 0; i++) { if (!string.charAt(i).equals(" ") { endIndex = i; break; } } int numSpaces = startIndex - endIndex;

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you cannot change the contents of a `String` object since it's immutable (cannot change after construction).

So in order to accomplish this:

```
String space = "";
for(int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++) {
    space += " ";
}
```

You need to use a `StringBuilder` object:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++) {
    sb.append(" ");
}
String space = sb.toString();
```

As I said, it is not a direct answer to your question, and there are probably more efficient solutions to the problem at hand. So it's just something for you to start with...

Answer (score 0):

```
int i= index;
int spaces = 0;
while(i>0 && string.charAt(i).equals(" ")){
    i--;
    spaces ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a Fast Regular expression? Thisone finds all the space characters inside the 1st group, and returns with the length of the match.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" +");
int count = pattern.matcher(input).group(0).length()
```